# How do I move a file from local to HDFS in Python?

Tags: python, shell, hdfs

I have a script to check a directory for files. If the right files (with keyword) is present, I want to move that/those file(s) to an HDFS location.

```py
import os
tRoot = "/tmp/mike"
keyword = "test"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tRoot):
    for file in files:
        if keyword in file:
            fullPath = str(os.path.join(root, file))
        subprocess.call(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-copyFromLocal','/tmp/mike/test*','hdfs:///user/edwaeadt/app'], shell=True)
```

I'm seeing below error:

```
Usage: hdfs [--config confdir] [--loglevel loglevel] COMMAND
```

I also tried with

```
 subprocess.call(['hadoop', 'fs', '-copyFromLocal', '/tmp/mike/test*', 'hdfs:///user/edwaeadt/app'], shell=True)
```

But I'm seeing

```
Usage: hadoop [--config confdir] [COMMAND | CLASSNAME]
  CLASSNAME
```

Also, seems like this loop is running 3 times. Because I now see the file moved to hdfs location but I also see twice where it says file exists. Seems like this copyFromLocal is running 3 times. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are intent on using subprocess and shell=True then your command should read as

```
subprocess.call(['hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /tmp/mike/test* hdfs:///user/edwaeadt/app'], shell=True)
```

Comment: Is there a better option than subprocess and shell=True?